# init: sys_prop: permission denied uid:1003 name:service.bootanim.exit

Tags: android

First let me say my english is bad; And this question is about Android 4.1.1 JB kernel 3.0.8+ with CPU ARMv7 (rk3066) and with wifi realtek chip (rtl8188) that use the module rtl8192cu.ko

I when I use the command dmesg I get this error.

> **init: sys_prop: permission denied uid:1003  name:service.bootanim.exit**

This is the complete log

```
[   16.753277] Current WiFi chip is RTL8188CU.
[   16.804358] =======================================================
[   16.810667] ==== Launching Wi-Fi driver! (Powered by Rockchip) ====
[   16.817037] =======================================================
[   16.823366] RTL8192/RTL8188 USB WiFi driver (Powered by Rockchip,Ver 4.04) init.
[   16.830834] wifi_usb_init
[   16.833515] wifi_activate_usb
[   16.850733] acc_open
[   16.850754] acc_release
[   17.475773] DWC_OTG: ********vbus detect*********************************************
[   17.690214] DWC_OTG: ********soft connect!!!*****************************************
[   17.696222] DWC_OTG: USB SUSPEND
[   17.956322] usbcore: registered new interface driver rtl8192cu
[   17.964560] DWC_OTG: USB RESET
[   18.152100] android_work: sent uevent USB_STATE=CONNECTED
[   18.155527] DWC_OTG: USB RESET
[   18.678399] DWC_OTG: USB SUSPEND
[   18.813121] DWC_OTG: USB RESET
[   18.988550] DWC_OTG: USB RESET
[   19.208520] android_usb gadget: high speed config #1: android
[   19.208758] android_work: sent uevent USB_STATE=CONFIGURED
[   20.036774] .423.. MMC0 receive the message sd-Checking from VOLD.[sd_mmc]
[   20.054251] .423.. MMC0 receive the message sd-Mounted from VOLD.[sd_mmc]
[   20.816986] init: sys_prop: permission denied uid:1003  name:service.bootanim.exit
[   28.302548] EXT4-fs (mtdblock8): re-mounted. Opts: (null)
[   28.312133] EXT4-fs (mtdblock8): re-mounted. Opts: (null)
[   28.322669] EXT4-fs (mtdblock8): re-mounted. Opts: (null)
[   29.016577] EXT4-fs (mtdblock8): re-mounted. Opts: (null)
[   29.819425] EXT4-fs (mtdblock8): re-mounted. Opts: (null)
[   29.841503] EXT4-fs (mtdblock8): re-mounted. Opts: (null)
[   33.311095] =======================================================
[   33.311151] ==== Dislaunching Wi-Fi driver! (Powered by Rockchip) ====
[   33.311190] =======================================================
[   33.311229] RTL8192/RTL8188 USB WiFi driver (Powered by Rockchip,Ver 4.04) init.
[   33.311278] usbcore: deregistering interface driver rtl8192cu
[   33.314507] wifi_deactivate_usb
[   33.958996] Current WiFi chip is RTL8188CU.
[   34.489809] =======================================================
[   34.489832] ==== Launching Wi-Fi driver! (Powered by Rockchip) ====
[   34.489843] =======================================================
[   34.489856] RTL8192/RTL8188 USB WiFi driver (Powered by Rockchip,Ver 4.04) init.
[   34.489869] wifi_usb_init
[   34.489876] wifi_activate_usb
[   35.607899] usbcore: registered new interface driver rtl8192cu
[   50.878030] =======================================================
[   50.878086] ==== Dislaunching Wi-Fi driver! (Powered by Rockchip) ====
[   50.878126] =======================================================
[   50.878164] RTL8192/RTL8188 USB WiFi driver (Powered by Rockchip,Ver 4.04) init.
[   50.878212] usbcore: deregistering interface driver rtl8192cu
[   50.881408] wifi_deactivate_usb
[   51.535508] Current WiFi chip is RTL8188CU.
[   51.559128] =======================================================
[   51.570685] ==== Launching Wi-Fi driver! (Powered by Rockchip) ====
[   51.571912] =======================================================
[   51.571923] RTL8192/RTL8188 USB WiFi driver (Powered by Rockchip,Ver 4.04) init.
[   51.571930] wifi_usb_init
[   51.571934] wifi_activate_usb
[   52.688568] usbcore: registered new interface driver rtl8192cu
[   67.960620] =======================================================
[   67.960675] ==== Dislaunching Wi-Fi driver! (Powered by Rockchip) ====
[   67.960715] =======================================================
[   67.960753] RTL8192/RTL8188 USB WiFi driver (Powered by Rockchip,Ver 4.04) init.
[   67.960801] usbcore: deregistering interface driver rtl8192cu
[   67.963018] wifi_deactivate_usb
[   68.620475] Current WiFi chip is RTL8188CU.
[   68.644524] =======================================================
[   68.647145] ==== Launching Wi-Fi driver! (Powered by Rockchip) ====
[   68.647155] =======================================================
[   68.647162] RTL8192/RTL8188 USB WiFi driver (Powered by Rockchip,Ver 4.04) init.
[   68.647169] wifi_usb_init
[   68.647173] wifi_activate_usb
[   69.768118] usbcore: registered new interface driver rtl8192cu
[   85.040587] =======================================================
[   85.046937] ==== Dislaunching Wi-Fi driver! (Powered by Rockchip) ====
[   85.053526] =======================================================
[   85.056068] RTL8192/RTL8188 USB WiFi driver (Powered by Rockchip,Ver 4.04) init.
[   85.056125] usbcore: deregistering interface driver rtl8192cu
[   85.060078] wifi_deactivate_usb
[   85.717254] Current WiFi chip is RTL8188CU.
[   85.736085] =======================================================
[   85.742419] ==== Launching Wi-Fi driver! (Powered by Rockchip) ====
[   85.748697] =======================================================
[   85.754975] RTL8192/RTL8188 USB WiFi driver (Powered by Rockchip,Ver 4.04) init.
[   85.755820] wifi_usb_init
[   85.755827] wifi_activate_usb
[   86.878055] usbcore: registered new interface driver rtl8192cu
[  102.149690] =======================================================
[  102.149746] ==== Dislaunching Wi-Fi driver! (Powered by Rockchip) ====
[  102.149785] =======================================================
[  102.149824] RTL8192/RTL8188 USB WiFi driver (Powered by Rockchip,Ver 4.04) init.
[  102.149872] usbcore: deregistering interface driver rtl8192cu
[  102.153550] wifi_deactivate_usb
[  102.803369] Current WiFi chip is RTL8188CU.
[  102.833477] =======================================================
[  102.835839] ==== Launching Wi-Fi driver! (Powered by Rockchip) ====
[  102.835847] =======================================================
[  102.835854] RTL8192/RTL8188 USB WiFi driver (Powered by Rockchip,Ver 4.04) init.
[  102.835860] wifi_usb_init
[  102.835864] wifi_activate_usb
[  103.957446] usbcore: registered new interface driver rtl8192cu
[  119.228043] =======================================================
[  119.234387] ==== Dislaunching Wi-Fi driver! (Powered by Rockchip) ====
[  119.240965] =======================================================
[  119.246149] RTL8192/RTL8188 USB WiFi driver (Powered by Rockchip,Ver 4.04) init.
[  119.246206] usbcore: deregistering interface driver rtl8192cu
[  119.249319] wifi_deactivate_usb
[  119.913704] Current WiFi chip is RTL8188CU.
[  119.941932] =======================================================
[  119.941947] ==== Launching Wi-Fi driver! (Powered by Rockchip) ====
[  119.941953] =======================================================
[  119.941960] RTL8192/RTL8188 USB WiFi driver (Powered by Rockchip,Ver 4.04) init.
[  119.941967] wifi_usb_init
[  119.941971] wifi_activate_usb
[  121.056387] usbcore: registered new interface driver rtl8192cu
[  124.971905] standby rt5631
[  136.333730] =======================================================
[  136.333787] ==== Dislaunching Wi-Fi driver! (Powered by Rockchip) ====
[  136.333826] =======================================================
[  136.333864] RTL8192/RTL8188 USB WiFi driver (Powered by Rockchip,Ver 4.04) init.
[  136.333912] usbcore: deregistering interface driver rtl8192cu
[  136.338449] wifi_deactivate_usb
[  139.551348] Current WiFi chip is RTL8188CU.
[  139.572226] =======================================================
[  139.572250] ==== Launching Wi-Fi driver! (Powered by Rockchip) ====
[  139.572256] =======================================================
[  139.572263] RTL8192/RTL8188 USB WiFi driver (Powered by Rockchip,Ver 4.04) init.
[  139.572270] wifi_usb_init
[  139.572274] wifi_activate_usb
[  140.688038] usbcore: registered new interface driver rtl8192cu
[  146.402600] standby rt5631
[  155.960611] =======================================================
[  155.965901] ==== Dislaunching Wi-Fi driver! (Powered by Rockchip) ====
[  155.965946] =======================================================
[  155.965987] RTL8192/RTL8188 USB WiFi driver (Powered by Rockchip,Ver 4.04) init.
[  155.966036] usbcore: deregistering interface driver rtl8192cu
[  155.968330] wifi_deactivate_usb
[  178.622627] standby rt5631
[  196.311997] standby rt5631
[  210.001941] init: untracked pid 1284 exited
[  218.112582] standby rt5631
[  274.262644] standby rt5631
[  303.909438] standby rt5631
[  322.380673] store_file: "/dev/block/vold/31:9"
[  322.918948] .423.. MMC0 receive the message sd-Unmounting from VOLD.[sd_mmc]
[  322.926019] .440.. MMC0 receive the message Unmounting(waitTimes=1) from VOLD.[sd_mmc]
[  324.016152] .423.. MMC0 receive the message sd-Idle-Unmounted from VOLD.[sd_mmc]
[  324.028209] store_file: "/dev/block/vold/179:0"
[  324.032937] .423.. MMC0 receive the message sd-Shared-Unmounted from VOLD.[sd_mmc]
[  329.272522] standby rt5631
[  386.373061] store_file: ""
[  386.854335] store_file: ""
[  386.857846] .423.. MMC0 receive the message sd-Idle-Unmounted from VOLD.[sd_mmc]
[  388.058410] .423.. MMC0 receive the message sd-Checking from VOLD.[sd_mmc]
[  388.068212] .423.. MMC0 receive the message sd-Mounted from VOLD.[sd_mmc]
[  395.024711] standby rt5631
[  409.432033] standby rt5631
[  428.441821] standby rt5631
[  451.232150] standby rt5631
[  503.262307] standby rt5631
[  522.991990] standby rt5631
[  570.962569] standby rt5631
[  589.581880] standby rt5631
```

WiFi won't work, so what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

This **permission denied** error has nothing to do with your WiFi module. Such error is caused by bootanimation service called from init. Bootanimation just trying to set some "setprop" and doesn't have proper rights for this action.
Try to switch this service in init - to more suitable like user system (but IMO your card still wouldn't start work properly).

Change from this:

```
service bootanim /system/bin/bootanimation
class main
user graphics
group graphics
disabled
oneshot
```

To that:

```
service bootanim /system/bin/bootanimation
class main
user system
group graphics
disabled
oneshot
```

This error as I observed doing no harm for any module (or other process) in system so you can just ignore it.